# Checking for and counting punctuation in a file

Tags: java

I'm currently doing an assignment which requires the program to count words and punctuation from a text file. The word counting program is done and working but my professor provided an additional method to be combined with it to count punctuation that I cannot seem to get to work. Here is the working program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SnippetWeek11 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a filename of a text file to process: ");
String filename = input.nextLine();
File file = new File(filename);
if (file.exists()) {
processFile(file);
 }
else {
System.out.println("File " + filename + " does not exist");
  }
 }

private static void processFile(File theFile) throws Exception {
int wordIndex;
// Create a TreeMap to hold words as key and count as value
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(theFile);
String line, keyText;
String[] words;
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
line = input.nextLine();
words = line.split("[\\s+\\p{P}]");
for (wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < words.length; wordIndex++) {
keyText = words[wordIndex].toLowerCase();
updateMap(map, keyText);
 }
}

// Display key and value for each entry
map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + "\t" + value));
}

    private static void updateMap(Map<String, Integer> theMap,
    String theText) {
    int value;
    String key = theText.toLowerCase();

    if (key.length() > 0) {
    if (!theMap.containsKey(key)) {
    // The key does not exist in the Map object (theMap), so add key and
    // the value (which is a count in this case) to a new theMap element.
    theMap.put(key, 1);
    }
    else {
    // The key already exists, so obtain the value (count in this case)
    // from theMap element that contains the key and update the element
    // with an increased count.
    value = theMap.get(key);
    value++;
    theMap.put(key, value);
    }
    }
    }
```

And here is the method that must be combined with the word count program. I would appreciate any help you could give. Thanks.

```
    public static int countPunctuation(File theFile) throws Exception {
    String[] punctuationString = {"[","]",".",";",",",":","!","?","(",")","{","}","'"};

    Set<String> punctuationSet =
    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(punctuationString));
    int count = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(theFile);

    while (input.hasNext()) {
    String character = input.next();
    if (punctuationSet.contains(character))
    count++;
    }
    return count;
    }
   }
```

Comment: You're comparing `Strings` against single character `Strings`, which would work if your punctuation was separated from words with spaces, but I gather they're not (for instance `"The end."` would need to be `"The end ."`). `input.next()` parses out a `String` separated by one or more spacing characters (`\s`, `\t`, ...). If you want to step through every character then you should change `input`'s delimiter to `.` using `input.useDelimiter(".")`.

Answer (score 1):

If you could use `Pattern` Class, you can do this.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class PunctuationMatch
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[,|.|?|!|:|;]");
        System.out.println(p.splitAsStream("Hello, World! How are you?").count());
    }
}
```

While passing string in `compile` method pass all the puctuation you want to identify.

Passing into `splitAsStream` method your entire data string or a line by line of a file and add every thing up.

Here is the [Java Docs Ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)